# How to exclude files in Fleet explorer

Tags: jetbrains-fleet

In VSCode we can exclude some files from being shown by adding the following to settings.json:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/*.exe": true
  },
```

How do I do this in Fleet?

Comment: As I get it it should be similar -- by editing the `settings.json` file. Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/settings.html#reference-miscellaneous -- "`excluded` -- array of strings -- Specifies directories that will not be indexed or scanned for configuration files. The directories are specified relative to the workspace root in the following format: `"excluded": ["dir1", "dir2"]`"

Comment: @LazyOne Thats not working, it still shows the files even after I added ```"excluded": ["**/*.exe"]``` to settings.json

Comment: Yeah. Based on the docs description/example it may work with the folders only and specific folders (no patterns)....

Answer (score 1):

To exclude files or folders from the File tree, you can specify `"files.exclude"` property in the `settings.json` file as in the following guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/settings.html#files.exclude